# What does Mexico consider to be a valid travel document to enter and use in Mexico?

Tags: paperwork, mexico

On the page [Visas - Traveling to Mexico](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico) from Mexico consulate website it says

> **Effective March 1st 2010**, all visitors traveling to Mexico either by air, land or sea are required to present a valid (non-expired)
>   Passport or Travel Document from their country to enter Mexico.

I am trying to figure out what a valid "Travel Document" is, specifically for traveling in Mexico.  Obviously separate to a Passport (as that is mentioned separately), I'm wondering if this would include things like a US Passport card, SENTRI card, Enhanced Driver licenses as can be used to re-enter the US from Mexico?

To clarify: What does **Mexico** consider to be a valid travel document **to enter and use in Mexico**?

Comment: The passport card, SENTRI card, and EDL cannot be used in lieu of a passport for air travel; they're only valid on their own for land and water.

Comment: @phoog But are they _officially_ accepted by Mexico authorities as valid travel documents (via land and water)?

Comment: I don't know.  That's why I commented rather than answering.

Comment: The Wikipedia [Travel document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_document) seems to limit the term to very passport-like documents.

Comment: Your quote says you need a "Travel Document from their country to enter Mexico." yet you did not specify what YOUR country is. Therefore, this question is not answerable.

Comment: @AussieJoe How is it unanswerable? The answer is clearly something like "A passport, or document X if you're from countries A, B or C, or document Y if you're from A, B, D or E, or..."

Comment: @DavidRicherby it is unanswerable because the OP did not say he is from "countries A, B, or C". That's why. If you read the comments in my answer, you'll see that important detail is left out.

Comment: @AussieJoe Consider the question "How long does it take to get from Paris to Berlin?" Your answer is "This is unanswerable, because you haven't said how you're travelling." The actual answer is, "It takes X hours by plane, Y hours by train, Z hours if you drive, ..." You don't need to know what country somebody is from to give a list of options. If you want to object that the list is too long, you might have a point, but the list exists. That list is the answer, therefore the question is not unanswerable.

Comment: @DavidRicherby it absolutely IS unanswerable if the OP is unwilling to provide the information necessary to determine what travel documents are required for their home country. The question clearly states "from their country". So what country is it? You have an answer?

Comment: @AussieJoe I give up. I have explained twice why this question is answerable. You have answered it yourself! Yet you insist that it is unanswerable.

Comment: The more this question evolves and unravels, the more likely the answer is going to be "Passport". They won't accept enhanced drivers license from non-Americans. Enhanced drivers license is only accepted with American entry points for North American citizens.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I dont see an answer. What is the nationality? You don't know it and you don't have the answer. Of course you give up!

Comment: @AussieJoe I'm not engaging in this any more.

Comment: @AussieJoe I am not asking specifically what I need to enter Mexico.  I am asking what Mexico considers to be a travel document.  How does Mexico define travel document?  If you *know* that this is a huge list that would require more information, then answer with that.  But I'm thinking that Travel Document may be more like what [Patricia Shanahan has commented](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115392/what-does-mexico-consider-to-be-a-valid-travel-document-to-enter-and-use-in-mexi?noredirect=1#comment281593_115392) above, which doesn't appear to be country specific at all.

Comment: @Midavalo really? You're contradicting yourself because your question title is actually "What does Mexico consider to be a valid travel document to enter and use in Mexico?", which implies entry and use in Mexico. Your question never was clear. Also, I entered Mexico this past weekend, walked across, paid 50 cents and didn't provide any travel documents. So your question still isnt clear.

Comment: @AussieJoe Where is the contradiction?  My question is and always has been "what does Mexico consider to be a valid travel document to enter and use in Mexico?" - nothing to do with me or where I live or come from.  I reference the Mexico consulate website which mentions Travel Documents, and I wanted to know what they were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by Patricia Shanahan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115392/what-does-mexico-consider-to-be-a-valid-travel-document-to-enter-and-use-in-mexi?noredirect=1#comment281593_115392) and confirmed to me by the Mexico Consulate, Travel Documents are *very passport-like documents*, such as those

> ...issued by governments for citizens of other countries that they have a special immigration situation and they cannot get a document for their country...

Basically passports for people who, due to special situations, cannot get passports from their own country.

Enhanced Driver Licenses, SENTRI pass, NEXUS cards, Birth Certificates are **not** considered to be travel documents, and cannot be used to enter Mexico.

The US Passport Card *can* be used by US citizens to enter Mexico by land (crossing the border from US to Mexico), otherwise a Passport (or the above Travel Document) is required for all non-Mexican citizens to enter Mexico.

Comment: funny, I went to Nuevo Progreso this weekend, walked across, entered Mexico for 50 USD cents, and didn't have to provide a passport or any identification. I bought prescription drugs, cuban cigars and ate a meal fit for a king. The way this question is worded, I could validly answer with my own experience this weekend (no passport).

Comment: @AussieJoe I don't doubt it, I know people who have entered Mexico without the required documentation.  However this will probably depend on the day and the INM officer you get.  It is possible that the next time you try it you could get denied entry if you don't have a passport.  And it's entirely possible that you'll have no problem at all.  This doesn't change what is officially required by Mexico, although possibly (probably) not enforced.

Answer (score 3):

By air, per the TIMATIC database used by airlines, it's a passport or certain other booklet-type travel documents, except for Mexican citizens who can use, among others, a national ID card (only exists for minors aged 4-17), voter's card with photo or Matricula Consular (for expat Mexicans)

By land, the US passport card is also accepted, per [the INM's FMM site](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your question clearly states

> "...or Travel Document from their country to enter Mexico"

is required, as instructed by the Mexican consulate's (of San Francisco California's) directions. You have have not stated what your nationality or country's passport is, therefore it's really hard to predict what travel documents Mexico will honor for your country. Again, you don't specify, so I think your answer is currently impossible.

And yes, you are correct. Mexican travel documents include US Passport card, Enhanced Driver license and also the Nexus/SENTRI/FAST cards. If you intend to travel by air, a passport is always required. Any other type of transportation, you can use the non passport travel documents. If you're a US citizen, you must always present your passport no matter the method of travel.

[This Frommer's article, "Can I Use a Driver License to Drive into Mexico or Canada?"](https://www.frommers.com/tips/entry-requirements-customs/can-i-use-a-driver-license-to-drive-into-mexico-or-canada) also explains how to enter Mexico by land.

> Now drivers need one of these to cross the U.S.-Mexico border by land:
>
> - U.S. citizens can present a valid U.S. passport or passport card
>     (click here to find out how to apply for those); an Enhanced Driver’s
>     License (which is a new type of license that proves your
>     citizenship—click here for information about those); a card from one
>     of the Trusted Traveler Programs (NEXUS, SENTRI or FAST)
> - You can also use one of these niche forms of identification, if you qualify: a U.S. Military identification card as long as you are traveling on
>     official orders, a U.S. Merchant Mariner document if you are traveling
>     in conjunction with official maritime business, a Form I-872 American
>     Indian Card, or (if it's available) an Enhanced Tribal Card.
> - U.S.
>     and Canadian citizen children under the age of 16 (or under 19, if
>     traveling with a school, religious group, or other youth group) need
>     only present a birth certificate or other proof of citizenship. The
>     birth certificate can be original, photocopy, or certified copy.
> - U.S. Lawful Permanent Residents are required to present their
>     permanent resident card (Form I-551) or other valid evidence of
>     permanent residence status.
> - Canadian citizens can present a valid
>     passport, Enhanced Driver’s License, or Trusted Traveler Program card
>     (NEXUS, SENTRI or FAST).
> - Bermudian citizens are required to present
>     a valid passport.
> - Mexican citizens, including children, are required
>     to present a passport with visa, or a Border Crossing Card.

The article also mentions that not all border crossings can read Enhanced Driver's Licenses.

> If you have an Enhanced Driver's License, bear in mind that not all border crossings have the capability to read them.

Comment: This answer tells me what is needed to enter the USA, not what is valid for entry into Mexico.

Comment: @Midavalo your question is not clear. Also, the Frommer's article specifically explains how to enter Mexico by land. So what exactly is your question???? Your original question states "I'm wondering if this would include things like a US Passport card, SENTRI card, Enhanced Driver licenses as can be used to re-enter the US from Mexico?" but you keep asking about entry to Mexico?

Comment: @Midavalo I would suggest contacting Mexico authorities but it seems their website is down.

Comment: @Midavalo you must be reading something different because the top of the article says "What documents to American citizens require if they want to cross by land into Mexico or Canada?" I added it to my answer.

Comment: Yes, it does.  However It should probably say "What documents do American citizens require to re-enter the United States if they want to cross by land into Mexico or Canada"

Comment: @Midavalo I think you're reading that wrong. That's the instructions for going into Mexico, at an American entry point. Read the article, it clearly explains that. Are you not a US citizen? If not, you might want to update your question?? I've contacted the US Embassy in Mexico city to find an answer.

Comment: This article is about how to re-enter the US.  Why would a Mexico citizen require a Passport with a Visa or a US-issued Border Crossing Card to enter Mexico?  All of the requirements are about ID issued by the US in order to enter the US.  Why would Mexico accept all these non-passport forms of ID?

Comment: @Midavalo the article CLEARLY only discusses going into Canada or going into Mexico. You never bothered to mention you're a Mexican citizen until this moment either. I suggest updating your question to reflect it. And since you're in Mexico, CONTACT YOUR LOCAL EMBASSY to find the answer since their website does not work!!!

Comment: I am not a Mexico citizen - I mention the Mexico citizen part because that is quoted by you from that website, but if it's for *entry* into Mexico, then this requirement doesn't make sense!

Comment: @Midavalo their website is blocked by firewall for me...but everything mentioned in English suggests using a Passport Card, if not a passport. Your travel documents will be dictated by your nationality. You posted that in your question, so it's really quite impossible to answer your question without that information.

Comment: the Frommer's article has been updated